# SQL join question

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `table_a` with a column containing data as follows:

```
.aaa01932
.asd02343
.lkj03342
```

So it always starts with a period followed by 3 letters, followed by 2 number (01, 02 etc) followed by some extra numbers.

I have another table `table_b` with data as follows:

```
aaa01
asd02
lkj03
```

So it maps to the data in `table_a` but with the period and the extra numbers at the end omitted.

How do I select from `table_a` joining on `table_b` where the data in the shown columns are "equal".  By equal I mean that `table_a.the_column` like '%table_b.the_column%'.  So something like:

```
Select * from table_a 
  join table_b on (table_a.the_column like '%table_b.the_column%');
```

Except I don't know how to format that like clause to accept a column inside. Maybe I need to concatenate it in somehow?

Comment: By using the '%' in the begining , you won't be able to use any index on this field, so not very efficient to join on this column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax for the LIKE would be:

```
table_a.the_column like '%' || table_b.the_column || '%'
```

An alternative would be SUBSTR:

```
table_b.the_column = substr(table_a.the_column,2,5)
```

As some comments have said, the SUBSTR is a better method for 2 reasons:

- It can be indexed:

  create index on table_a (substr(the_column,2,5));
- It is more accurate: you want to match only in that position, not **anywhere** in the column

Comment: substr will be more suitable in this case (fixed lenght), we can use index at least.

Comment: `SUBSTR` would be better, assuming the pattern is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select * from table_a 
  join table_b on (table_a.the_column like '%' || table_b.the_column || '%');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
join table_b on substr(table_a.column,1) = table_b.column
```

Comment: I believe this is a better option than LIKE, since we can use index in this case. Also to be more precise : substr(table_a.column,2,5)

Comment: I mean `substr('.aaa01932',1)` would produce `'aaa01932'` and then we'll try to join on this condition `'aaa01932' = 'aaa01'`